# Excel formula to find last occurrence of a value in a column (with conditions)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So I basically want to find the index (position) of the last value which meets a certain amount of conditions.

Here is an example of the formula I use to find the FIRST match:

```
={MATCH(1,(Sheet!$B5:$B50000=$B$3)*(Sheet!$D5:$D50000>$E$3)*(C$8=Sheet!$A5:$A50000)*(Sheet!$E5:$E50000="CALLINBOUND"),0)}
```

This works fine, I'm finding the first "CALLINBOUND" value in E5:E50000 after checking some other conditions (basically B5:B50000 are IDs, D5:D50000 are hours and A5:A50000 are dates).

Now, let's say I want to find the last "CALLINBOUND" value in that same E5:E50000 range with the same conditions:

```
Sheet!$B5:$B50000=$B$3
Sheet!$D5:$D50000>$E$3
C$8=Sheet!$A5:$A50000
Sheet!$E5:$E50000="CALLINBOUND"
```

How should I proceed?

I found a couple of answers using MAX() and SUMPRODUCT() or LOOKUP() but it only returns the last match in a range without checking for any condition, so I'm kind of stuck. Also, if there is any way to optimize the performance of the above formula, that would be appreciated. The range will eventually grow and it's slow with array formulas.

I may use Access in the future, I guess this would be easier with SQL than with pure Excel formulas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2007 or earlier than use this array formula:

```
=Max(IF((Sheet!$B5:$B50000=$B$3)*(Sheet!$D5:$D50000>$E$3)*(C$8=Sheet!$A5:$A50000)*(Sheet!$E5:$E50000="CALLINBOUND"),Row($5:$50000)))
```

Being an Array the use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode.

If you have 2010 or later you could use:

```
=Aggregate(14,6,Row($5:$50000)/((Sheet!$B5:$B50000=$B$3)*(Sheet!$D5:$D50000>$E$3)*(C$8=Sheet!$A5:$A50000)*(Sheet!$E5:$E50000="CALLINBOUND")),1)
```

If you have the latest Office 365 or are using the online version then:

```
=MAXIFS(Row($5:$50000),Sheet!$B5:$B50000,$B$3,Sheet!$D5:$D50000,">" & $E$3,Sheet!$A5:$A50000,C$8,Sheet!$E5:$E50000,"CALLINBOUND")
```

If you wanted to replace your current formula to find the first then in the first change MAX to MIN.  In the Second change 14 to 15.  In the Third change MAXIFS to MINIFS

Comment: I have Office 2010, I will give this a try, thank you. @Scott Craner

Comment: Haven't had time to try more scenarios to be sure it's working correctly, I'm sorry. Why does it matter that much anyway? I upvoted your answer but would happily downvote your comment if I could, I will take the time I need to do more testing, and since you don't seem willing to give a more detailed answer about what your formulas do exactly, I might have to do some more search before posting a more detailed answer of my own. I also asked for alternatives to array formulas to gain performance improvement and you just ignored that part completely.

Comment: @dnLL as far as I know the only way to do this without array formulas is to use vba and you did not ask for that.  I routinely go through my answers and try to get the OP to choose one answer, even if it is not mine to close the question, so that it gets removed from the open questions.  It is not the points but the ocd in me that dislikes forgotten questions.